# require.js: how to debug scripterror?

Tags: javascript, debugging, requirejs

I am trying to get started with require.js. I have a test page which loads test.js. It has a bunch of dependencies which reported fairly easy-to-fix errors which have now all gone away, but test.js is now failing. I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Script error for "test"
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
require.js:168:17
```

I have commented out everything in test.js so that all I'm left with is this:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'lib',
  paths: {
    app: '../app'
  }
});

requirejs.onError = function (err) {
  console.log(err.requireType);
  if (err.requireType === 'timeout') {
    console.log('modules: ' + err.requireModules);
  }
  throw err;
};

require(["A","B","C","app/D","app/E","app/F"],
        function (A,B,C,D,E,F) { }
);
```

I can't see what could be wrong here (mind you, I've said that before...). The exception gives a stack trace on the console listing dozens of lines inside require.js itself, but I have absolutely no idea what it is trying to do when it fails.

Does anyone have any idea how to debug in situations like this to find out what on earth is going on?

Comment: I have found what was causing the problem (my data-main in the script tag referred to "lib/test" instead of just "test"), but it took me a day's work to find this. So my original question remains: Is there any way to persuade require.js to give meaningful error messages rather than "it just failed somewhere, up you you to figure out why"?

Comment: Sadly, there is not way to improve this. This is the bad part of RequireJS. Why are giving a chance to RequireJS? It is quite old :)

Comment: I am porting an old Java applet which has a main() so it can also be run as a standalone application, so I want something that works both in Node and in a browser. This is what I found when I went looking. I don't care that it's old, I just care that it works! I'm open to suggestions for something that will do what I want but might be easier to work with...?

Comment: How big is the app? What about build tool like webpack?

Comment: Not that big, but it's a modular system in about a couple of dozen separate files since different deployment situations require different sets of classes (which used to be loaded on demand by the Java classloader based on a config file). I'll look at webpack and see if it can do the trick. Thanks for the lead.